# I'm getting a TemplateSyntaxError in my local django server at my template html file regarding the block tag that I used

Tags: html, django

"Invalid block tag on line 2: 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?"

---

This is the error I'm getting and the following is my code in my index.html file in vs code which for some reason keeps getting aligned into one line after saving despite saving each block as a different line after one another:

---

{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block body %} This is body block {% endblock body
%}

[This is the image of the error I'm getting in my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYn4c.png)

[And this is the code I wrote and saved as it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPyxq.png)

It somehow works after I save it, but after a few minutes it becomes like image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYn4c.png) and gives me an error :(

Edit: I guess "prettier" extension was the culprit, as disabling it seems to work for now. Thanks for the help

Comment: Ensure there's no space between `{` and `%`

Comment: Share your template.

Comment: Do you have some feature like format on save configured in your IDE? Turn it off, it seems to not understand that your file is a Django template and breaks your syntax.